# How to wrap assemblies in .NET?

Tags: c#, wrapper

In ordinary native libraries, I can wrap another dll and monitor calls by simply building a dll with the same exact function signatures in the export, and sometimes can even call onto the real dll.

In managed C#, I have a dll called "A" that is a plugin for another application that has a class that derives from a class in another dll I called dll "B". I want to make a wrapper dll for "B", so "A" can function with a wrapped version of "B", and might not even use the real version of "B" at all.

B also has static methods and other classes, I want to be able to redefine the signatures/declarations in this quasi-wrapper and have the "A" assembly use that instead.

Plugin dll A:

```
using baseDllB;
public class foopluginA : pluginclassB
{
   public void methodbaz() { base.doStuff(); pluginclassB.doStaticStuff(); }
}
```

Base dll B:

```
namespace baseDllB
{
   public class pluginclassB
   {
       public void doStuff()
       {
        //Do stuff
       }
       public static void doStaticStuff() { /*Do more stuff*/ }
   }
}
```

The plugin `dll`s reference B obviously, so what I want to do is recreate `B` where I'm able to perform logging, etc.

What ways are there to do this?

Comment: Program to an Interface and not an implementation... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write an assembly which had a class that forwarded all of its method calls and internal state to other classes.  However, there are a few difficulties you'd have to overcome.

You would have to replace references to the original assembly with your new wrapper assembly.

You would have to reflect class changes in the wrapper to the wrapped class.  This can be non-trivial, especially if the internal state contains private members.  If it's a static class, that's a lot easier.

If you wanted your wrapper assembly to be able to load more than one kind of wrapped assembly, for example to choose which class to forward to, you would either need to write an interface and make the wrapped assemblies derive from that interface, or your code in your wrapper assembly would become very complex.

If you wanted your wrapper assembly to be totally dynamic, meaning it loaded its wrapped target at runtime and only the one you wanted, you'd need to make heavy use of reflection to get methods and other items from the wrapped class.

Comment: I have no access to the source code of base class. The reason why I'm not compiling the source inside my test-bed is because of the deployment issues of having to cut code out and recompile, and that I need resources to be embedded into the plugin and not the test-bed.

Comment: I left several options here -- in my last one I mention reflection.  Using that you can get the info on every member, public or private, method or property or field, of any class or value type.

Comment: Well reflection is mandatory, the issue now is getting an inherited class in a dll to inherit from a wrapped class. But you know what I just tried? Re-implementing every member, static class, etc, to create my own copy of the "B" class, and it works. It used the copy without any errors, but should I be aware of any issues down the road using this method?

Comment: There should not be any issues.  If you wanted perfect replacement you could design an interfaces, but if you don't mind changing a small amount of code the way you did it is fine.

Comment: Had interfaces been used for the plugin model I would never have asked, but the plugins rely on a inherited class and several static methods located in various other classes in the "B" dll. Since I wasn't the one who designed the plugin model, I agree it would have been trivial to simplify the model.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is `RealProxy`. You can use [the `RealProxy` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx) to provide proxy instances of other classes, and the client code won't know the difference. [Here is a blog post with an example of its usage](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/07/17/Creating-proxies-with-RealProxy.aspx).

Comment: This actually looks viable enough. I'm dynamically loading the assembly, how would I get the target class to inherit from a proxy?

Comment: Also, if this doesn't work. I heard in another comment (disappeared mysteriously), that there was a something I can set to disable verification, what can I do to make the plugin load a simple build of the "B" library that simply reimplements the original "B" with the same exact member and class names?

Comment: Suppose I've built a library with same exact class, defining all the exact methods etc. After dynamically loading the plugin, is there anyway for me to direct its inherited dependency to the copy? Assuming that I can do that in the first place :s

Comment: Hrm, I'm not sure how you'd go about that. If you have no control at all over the application and DLL then this might be difficult... RealProxy only works on interfaces or types that derive from MarshalByRefObject, so if you can't alter that then you will have issues using it.

Comment: Hm, bummer. Couldn't even go forward with using RealProxy much less than fowarding a base class.