# Intercepting calls to a method in another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way to do the following, possibly by reflection? Reflection isn't required. Any method is acceptable.

I have two assemblies, VenderAssembly (I do not have the source code) and MyAssembly. I would like to invoke `MyAssembly.MyMethod` whenever `VenderAssembly.VendorMethod` is invoked where MyAssembly is not the assembly responsible for invoking `VenderMethod`.

I do not need access to the argument values being passed to `VendorMethod`. I just need to trigger `MyMethod` each and every time `VendorMethod` is invoked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subscribing an Action to any event type via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753366/subscribing-an-action-to-any-event-type-via-reflection)

Comment: So `VenderAssembly` doesn't actually have an event, correct?

Comment: Is VendorAssembly strong signed?

Comment: @MattBurland: No, it has a method according to the post.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933581/wrap-assemblies-in-net

Comment: I'd take a step back and question *why* you need to do this. This is deliberately a difficult (and maybe impossible in the case of a signed assembly) thing to do and any solution is likely to be hacky and not robust. If you were working entirely in your own assemblies, you might potentially be able to just wrap the venders class in a class of your own and have all calling code use your wrapper. But if you are trying to detect calls from a third assembly that you can't change, then you might be out-of-luck.

Comment: @MattBurland: I'm not sure if the assembly is signed. It sounds like I'm going down the wrong path here. The vendor method in question is the Application_Start event of an Asp.net application. I need to add routes to the routing table of the Vendors application so I can do some WebApi things within their app. If I inherit from their global class, write my own Application_Start, Asp.net still calls their Application_Start not mine due to AutoWireUp apparently using reflection to find Application_Start.

Comment: If I inherit directly from HttpApplication and call their Application_Start through reflection, both my Application_Start and theirs execute but theirs does not have access to the Application object so it fails with null reference exception. I asked this question because I was looking for a way to cause my Application_Start to execute whenever theirs does (I don't need access to the Application object that I know of)

Comment: Ok. So it sounds to me like you should probably start another question and ask the question of how to "add routes to an asp.net application in a third party assembly" (or words to that effect). Although, you might search first in case somebody has already answered that question. IMHO, this question is interesting in it's own right, so I wouldn't delete it.

Comment: BTW this question has absolutely nothing to do with events.  I think the right phrase would be "intercepting calls to a method in another assembly"

Comment: @Matt. Thanks. Since this question went down a dead-end path, I'll mark Patrick's "You can't really do this" answer below as the correct one. In the mean time, [would you mind having a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873108/application-start-wont-fire-when-inheriting-global-asax-from-a-vendors-global/25875722?noredirect=1#comment40506153_25875722) which was my first attempt at solving my original problem  ... I never got this quite to work although I felt I was close.

Comment: @Ben  I took your suggestion and changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a method 'dynamically' when another one is called.

You can't register on methods, you can only register on events. So unless your `VendorMethod()` calls an event `VendorMethodCalled`, which [you *can* subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753366/subscribing-an-action-to-any-event-type-via-reflection) to, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ziad Elmalki has written [a description of how to replace a method implementation at runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2009/03/29/msil-injection-rewrite-a-non-dynamic-method-at-runtime.aspx) and [published code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer).

It appears that the crucial part of the technique is to ask the JIT to compile a method with the same signature as the one to be replaced, and then overwrite the method table of the type (managed version of a vtbl) to refer to the new method.

The replacement will be unconditional, if you want to test whether the call is coming from outside the assembly, you'd need to do a stack walk (.NET makes this fairly easy).

Of course, this will fail to replace methods which are small enough for the JIT to choose to inline them.

Comment: Interesting...presumably you would need to grab the original method and rename it (or otherwise move it *somewhere*) so that your replacement stub could call the original since I assume the OP doesn't want to reimplement the whole method.

Comment: How would that work with signed assemblies? You can't resign them.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I think that's pretty much a given that if the assembly is signed, the OP is dead in the water.

Comment: @MattBurland: That seems a little harsh to OP (sorry, had to take a dictionary for that expression ;) ).

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Wasn't meant to sound harsh. Just meant the OP probably can't do what they are trying to do, which is pretty much exactly what you were saying.

Comment: @MattBurland: I know. Just showing my unfamiliarity with some English expressions.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I don't think signing would influence this in any way, since it's checked when the assembly is first loaded, and you aren't overwriting the file.  But you will need full trust to be able to overwrite CLR internal data structures, because that can only be done by either external native code or `unsafe` blocks.

Comment: @MattBurland: I think the original method table entry has the information needed to make a delegate.  As long as you did that before overwriting it, you could call the original.  But I don't see anywhere that Ziad tested that.